# Prevent mobiscroll from wrapping time-control down to new line on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, mobiscroll

I am using the mobiscroll jQuery library for a datetime picker. It works great on Safari for iPad and on Google Chrome. However, on Mozilla Firefox on PCs it seems to "line-break." In other words, after the date control, the time control gets wrapped down to the next line (see image below). I don't want this. I want it to be all on one line like on the other browsers. Any idea how to fix this with CSS or something else? TIA.

[image: Mobiscroll line-breaking]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got fixed with new release (2.0.3).